# javascript functions game

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have this source code:

```
  var Game = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('world');
  this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

I use some functions to deal with this class:

```
  Game.prototype.updateAll = function() {...}
```

and some another functions.

Now I want to use mouse functions ( click right , left ...)

I think is need to add in my Game class something like that:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.getmouse, false);
```

But the browser don't show me anything ...

How and where can be do this function in my class ?

Comment: Have you defined `Game.prototype.getmouse` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, `Game` has no `this.canvas`.  You defined a local variable with `var canvas`, but you need to set the `Game` member variable `this.canvas`.  If you want both, just follow your current `var canvas = ...` line with `this.canvas = canvas;`.